# Confusing cases in Piecewise

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, piecewise

The following

```
FullSimplify[Integrate[Exp[I ω t] Sin[ω x]/ω, {ω, 0, ∞},
  Assumptions -> t > 0 && x > 0]]
```

gives a piecewise output of the form

[image]

I don't understand this because $t\geq x$ is stronger than $t>x$ and yet $i \operatorname{arctanh}(x/t)$ isn't zero for $t>x$. I must be misinterpreting what this means but I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it might be confusing to a mathematician's eye, the output is computationally correct. Cases are evaluated in order from first to last (see second bullet-point in Details for [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)) . Therefore, for $t>x$, first condition applies (and other conditions are not checked), and for $t=x$, the second condition applies.

To make conditions disjoint, use [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html):

```
e = Integrate[Exp[I ω t] Sin[ω x]/ω, {ω, 0, ∞}, Assumptions -> t > 0 && x > 0];

PiecewiseExpand[e, Method -> {"OrderlessConditions" -> True}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: I get it. Thanks for this.

Comment: I get it. Thanks for this.